# Pandas groupby and compare to previous group

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to compare values, in this case names between dates I have in a dataframe. Assume following testframe:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample DataFrame with 'Date' and 'Name' columns
data = {
    'Date': ['2023-10-03', '2023-10-03', '2023-10-02', '2023-10-02', '2023-10-01', '2023-10-01'],
    'Name': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to create a new column e.g. "Check" that displays a 0 for all dates, where the name composition compared to previous date did not change, and a 1 where it changed. The desired outcome would be:

```
   Date          Name   Check
0  2023-10-03    A      0      # A/B, as previously
1  2023-10-03    B      0
2  2023-10-02    A      1      # A/B, changed
3  2023-10-02    B      1
4  2023-10-01    A      1      # A/C
5  2023-10-01    C      1
```

For '2023-10-03' the value is 0 because the names are exactly like for '2023-10-02', namely 'A', and 'B'. For the other 2 dates the name composition either changed or it is the first date observation.

Thanks!

Comment: what if rows index 2/3 were swapped? would it make a difference?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: If you swapped the A and B in rows with index 2 and 3, would you expectd the same output? if not what would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can aggregate as set (with [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)) and check if the composition changed with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
# ensure datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# get composition per Date
s = df.groupby('Date')['Name'].agg(set)

# check if composition is same as previous day
df['Check'] = df['Date'].map(s.ne(s.shift(1, freq='D')).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
        Date Name  Check
0 2023-10-03    A      0
1 2023-10-03    B      0
2 2023-10-02    A      1
3 2023-10-02    B      1
4 2023-10-01    A      1
5 2023-10-01    C      1
```

Intermediate `s`:

```
Date
2023-10-01    {C, A}
2023-10-02    {B, A}
2023-10-03    {B, A}
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

If you want to consider the next date in terms of order of the groups and not by actual shift of 1 day:

```
s = df.groupby('Date', sort=False)['Name'].agg(set)
df['Check'] = df['Date'].map(s.ne(s.shift(-1)).astype(int))
```

Or for the previous available date:

```
df['Check'] = df['Date'].map(df.groupby('Date', sort=True)['Name']
                               .agg(set).diff().ne(set()).astype(int))
```